# Replace image with placeholder on src change

Tags: vue.js

I have an image with a bound src value

```html
<img :src="image.url">
```

When `image.url` gets updated, the old image stays in place until the new image is loaded. This can look a little weird as the new image lags behind the text details on change.

How can I replace the image with a loading indicator when the `src` property changes with vue.js?

I could add DOM manipulation with the code that triggers the change and that works, but I'd rather do it properly with vue bindings.

Comment: how/where does the url change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you on the right track:

1. Have an `imageLoading` attribute in your `data()` function.
2. Set your :src as follows: `<img :src="imageLoading ? ./myPlaceholder.png : image.url" />`
3. $watch your image.url to set the loading image whenever it changes:

```js
watch: {
  'image.url': function() {
    this.imageLoading = true;
  }
```

4. Add an @load handler to your img tag to set imageLoading to false when the image loads: `<img :src="imageLoading ? ./myPlaceholder.png : image.url" @load="imageLoading = false" />`

Note on the @load handler - shamelessly stolen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051771/does-vue-js-not-trigger-a-load-event-for-img-when-v-if-is-used), which does link to an example.

Comment: `@load` is really what I needed! Thank you, I can make this work.

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic image placeholder component that uses slots to display any placeholder content

```
<template>
  <div class="image">
    <img :src="src" @load="ready = true" v-show="ready">
    <slot v-if="!ready" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['src'],
  data: () => ({
    ready: false
  }),
  watch: {
    src () { this.ready = false }
  }
}
</script>
```

to use it

```
<image-placeholder src="IMAGE_URL">
  <b>PLACEHOLDER CONTENT HERE</b>
  <p>Can be anything</p>
  <img src="ANOTHER_IMAGE_URL" />
</image-placeholder>
```